# Wanted to mock S3 data in python, modify that data and do assertion in unit tests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mocking

Wanted to mock S3 data in python, modify that data and do assertion in unit tests

So in short wanted to write a test case in which wanted to mock the S3 data, data contains timestamp, want to modify that, so that I can assert the values.

Comment: We are going to need more information in order to effectively help out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your post to include your attempted code, specific question/issue, and any other relevant supporting information.

Answer (score 0):

Testing against AWS Services can be done in various ways and depend on use-case and environment:

- Mock the S3 API with a mocking framework
- Create a tiny layer around the S3 API for the use case and mock this in tests
- Use a development S3 Bucket for testing
- Use localstack for local testing or deploy another server that supports the S3 protocol

It largely depends what the use case is and what exactly is needed.